# Acumatica. Customization using sender.SetValueExt

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create customization on Shipment Screen in Acumatica ERP.

I create additional customization to copy the `OpenOrderQty` to `ShippedQty` when we select the order number.

Here my code:

```
  public void SOShipLine_RowInserting(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertingEventArgs e, PXRowInserting baseMethod)
  {
      if (baseMethod != null)
          baseMethod(sender, e);

      SOShipLine line = e.Row as SOShipLine;

      if (line == null) return; // just in case
  
      if (line.ShippedQty == 0)
      {

        sender.SetValueExt<SOShipLine.ShippedQty>(line, line.OpenOrderQty);
      
      }
  }
```

But, when I publish the customization, there is an error:

> \App_RuntimeCode\SOShipmentEntry.cs(85): error CS0118:
> 'PX.Objects.SO.SOShipLine.ShippedQty' is a 'property' but is used like
> a 'type'

Is the problem with the `sender.SetValueExt`?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that error by using the '**s**hippedQty' variable instead of '**S**hippedQty'. Notice first letter is different case, lowercase vs uppercase.

Uppercase variable is a C# property and is used when you want to get the value or set the value of the field:

```
line.ShippedQty = 1M;
var myQuantity = line.ShippedQty;
```

Lowercase variable is used when you refer to the field as a type. When you provide the generic type (T) of SetValueExt you are not setting or getting the value of T. You are telling SetValueExt that it should use that type for setting the value of the line.ShippedQty field:

```
SetValueExt<SOShipLine.shippedQty>
```

When expecting a type (lowercaste) it will often be referred to as a Field parameter in visual studio intellisense:
[image]

Comment: Dear HB_Acumatica. the problem is done.
Base on your description lower case and upper case:

sender.SetValueExt<SOShipLine.ShippedQty>(line, line.OpenOrderQty);

I change ShippedQty to shippedQty

Thanks for your help.